# Can`t run powershell command with ProcessLauncher in Windows Iot core

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I faced a problem with **ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync( )** method and I can`t run powershell command with it, after i add some application to **AllowedExecutableFilesList** such as powershell.exe , cmd.exe , ipconfige.exe , ping.exe and so on in order to use this apps in my UWP app run in windows 10 iot core on Rasberry PI 3 model B.
I add the app to **AllowedExecutableFilesList** with below code :

```
   REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher" /v AllowedExecutableFilesList /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"\0"c:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe"\0"c:\Windows\System32\ping.exe"\0"c:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe"\0"c:\Windows\System32\CommProxy.exe"\0"c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe\0"
```

After that I write this piece of code to lunch powershell and sent command to process :

```
        var options = new ProcessLauncherOptions();
        var standardOutput = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var standardError = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        options.StandardOutput = standardOutput;
        options.StandardError = standardError;

       await CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                     var command = "get-date";
                     var path = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe";
                     var result = await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync(path, command, options);
                }
                catch
                {}
            });
        }
```

in ***ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync*** my app stuck and never back any correct or incorrect result. what should I do ?

Comment: You code works for me. You can check the CPU performance in [Device Portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal) and ensure CPU utilization is not very high and is able to run your app and launch the powershell. What's your OS version?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT my os build number is : 14393 and when use app my cpu usage around 25% to 55%.
at this line  **var result = await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync(path, args, options);** my app freezed , can you run get-date from powershell and catch the result ?

Comment: Have you add "`<iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />`" in Package.appxmanifest?

Comment: yes , i had added.can you run get-date command , and get the result back ?

Comment: Yes, I get the result back but it is an invalid date and time. I change the command to "Get-Date -format d" and get the right date.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Can you run other powershell command such as set-date and so on with ProcessLauncher class ?

Comment: Hi, when I run this code I get result with result core 0 but no data in buffer. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's now a bit late but I recently run into this issue. I tried to use `netsh` and `PowerShell` from within my UWP Application with the ProcessLauncher. My working solution is, I copied netsh.exe powershell.exe from the system32(Iot Arm Image) folder to my App Folder and used it locally.

```
OS => Windows Iot Version 10.0.17763.503
Board => Raspberry Pi 3
```

No registry entries or whatever else needed. Clean and simple

```
await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync("netsh.exe", "?", options);
```